# Unable to change desktop background using gsettings in Terminal

Tags: 16.04, command-line, desktop-background, gsettings

I need to change my background wallpaper through terminal. So I entered this line in terminal:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///appdev/wallpaper.jpg'
```

The output is:

```
Usage: gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] get SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY
Get the value of KEY
Arguments: SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
SCHEMA The name of the schema PATH The path, for relocatable schemas KEY The key within the schema
```

Also using `set` as shown below didn't work:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///appdev/wallpaper.jpg'
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: `gsettings get` gives you the current value of a setting, `gsettings set` changes it.

Comment: No it doesn't worked@Jos

Comment: Then at least edit your question with the output of `gsettings set`.

Comment: There doesn't came any out put for set@Jos anyway I have edited.